# Adding up all the values of child node to all parents

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

```
[
    {
        "level_key":"lvl1",
        "level_value":"Code1",
        "values":[
            {
                "name":"a",
                "value":0
            },
            {
                "name":"b",
                "value":0
            }
        ],
        "children":[
            {
                "level_key":"lvl2",
                "level_value":"Type1",
                "values":[
                    {
                        "name":"a",
                        "value":0
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"b",
                        "value":0
                    }
                ],
                "children":[
                    {
                        "level_key":"lvl3",
                        "level_value":"Desc1",
                        "values":[
                            {
                                "name":"a",
                                "value":0
                            },
                            {
                                "name":"b",
                                "value":0
                            }
                        ],
                        "children":[
                            {
                                "level_key":"lvl4",
                                "level_value":"Check1",
                                "values":[
                                    {
                                        "name":"a",
                                        "value":2
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name":"b",
                                        "value":3
                                    }
                                ],
                                "children":[]
                            },
                            {
                                "level_key":"lvl4",
                                "level_value":"Check2",
                                "values":[
                                    {
                                        "name":"a",
                                        "value":4
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name":"b",
                                        "value":5
                                    }
                                ],
                                "children":[]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have tried brute force in which i am looping max number of levels. That is wrong as number of levels is not fixed. Input:

[
{
"level_key":"lvl1",
"level_value":"Code1",
"values":[
{
"name":"a",
"value":0
},
{
"name":"b",
"value":0
}
],
"children":[
{
"level_key":"lvl2",
"level_value":"Type1",
"values":[
{
"name":"a",
"value":0
},
{
"name":"b",
"value":0
}
],
"children":[
{
"level_key":"lvl3",
"level_value":"Desc1",
"values":[
{
"name":"a",
"value":0
},
{
"name":"b",
"value":0
}
],
"children":[
{
"level_key":"lvl4",
"level_value":"Check1",
"values":[
{
"name":"a",
"value":2
},
{
"name":"b",
"value":3
}
],
"children":[]
},
{
"level_key":"lvl4",
"level_value":"Check2",
"values":[
{
"name":"a",
"value":4
},
{
"name":"b",
"value":5
}
],
"children":[]
}
]
}
]
}
]
}
]
I have tried brute force in which i am looping max number of levels. That is wrong as number of levels is not fixed. Input:

[
{
"level_key":"lvl1",
"level_value":"Code1",
"values":[
{
"name":"a",
"value":0
},
{
"name":"b",
"value":0
}
],
"children":[
{
"level_key":"lvl2",
"level_value":"Type1",
"values":[
{
"name":"a",
"value":0
},
{
"name":"b",
"value":0
}
],
"children":[
{
"level_key":"lvl3",
"level_value":"Desc1",
"values":[
{
"name":"a",
"value":0
},
{
"name":"b",
"value":0
}
],
"children":[
{
"level_key":"lvl4",
"level_value":"Check1",
"values":[
{
"name":"a",
"value":2
},
{
"name":"b",
"value":3
}
],
"children":[]
},
{
"level_key":"lvl4",
"level_value":"Check2",
"values":[
{
"name":"a",
"value":4
},
{
"name":"b",
"value":5
}
],
"children":[]
}
]
}
]
}
]
}
]
I have tried brute force in which i am looping max number of levels. That is wrong as number of levels is not fixed. Output i am expecting is:

```
[
    {
        "level_key":"lvl1",
        "level_value":"Code1",
        "values":[
            {
                "name":"a",
                "value":6
            },
            {
                "name":"b",
                "value":8
            }
        ],
        "children":[
            {
                "level_key":"lvl2",
                "level_value":"Type1",
                "values":[
                    {
                        "name":"a",
                        "value":6
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"b",
                        "value":8
                    }
                ],
                "children":[
                    {
                        "level_key":"lvl3",
                        "level_value":"Desc1",
                        "values":[
                            {
                                "name":"a",
                                "value":6
                            },
                            {
                                "name":"b",
                                "value":8
                            }
                        ],
                        "children":[
                            {
                                "level_key":"lvl4",
                                "level_value":"Check1",
                                "values":[
                                    {
                                        "name":"a",
                                        "value":2
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name":"b",
                                        "value":3
                                    }
                                ],
                                "children":[]
                            },
                            {
                                "level_key":"lvl4",
                                "level_value":"Check2",
                                "values":[
                                    {
                                        "name":"a",
                                        "value":4
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name":"b",
                                        "value":5
                                    }
                                ],
                                "children":[]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: With an unknown depth, recursion is often a good solution.

Comment: You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Please do not [repost your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75127746/want-to-add-up-all-the-values-inside-all-parents-of-a-leaf-node).

Comment: @FiddlingAway I will repost till i get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully get why you're nesting your levels as children of the upper level. But I suggest using a [reduce function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) combined with a [recursive function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-functions/) that you can use to map your items.

```js
function getTotal (key, children) {
  if (children.length > 0) {
    return children.reduce((acc, value) => {
      // Find the value item that has the value that we are looking for
      const valueItem = value.values.find((item) => item.name === key));
      
      // Add to the accumulator or zero if the item was not found
      return acc + (valueItem ? valueItem.value : 0);
    }, 0); // 0 means that the starting object is 0
  }

  // If no children, simply return 0
  return 0;
}

function applyValuesFromChildren(items) {
  return items.map((item) => {
    if (item.children.length > 0) {
      // This should first calculate & apply everything in the child items
      // This is the recursive part
      children = applyValuesFromChildren(item.children);
    } else {
      // End of the recursive functionality loop
      children = [];
    }

    const values = [];
    
    // Override the values with the calculated amounts of their children
    item.values.forEach((valueItem) => {
      const name = valueItem.name;
      const value = getTotal(name, children);
      
      // Create a new value item with the newly calculated value
      values.push({ name, value });
    });

    // Override values so that the parent can calculate using 
    // these newly assigned values
    item.values = values;
    item.children = children;
    return item;
  });
}
```

I have not tested this, but this should give you a start on how to use recursion to go through nested arrays endlessly in your use case.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer , can you pls tell why u returned zero at the last of getTotal, shouldnt we return the values of leaf node?

Comment: Because if there are no children in the leaf node (children array) there's no point in looking within that array. Simply returning 0 is in that case faster. @KapilBalwani